# What is the reference edf for generalized additive models?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, degrees-of-freedom, mgcv

From the summary of my fitted generalized additve model (gam) I see two edfs. The first edf is the model edf and second is the reference edf.
However, for AIC estimation, the reference edf is used. But what is the reason behind that?
As model is estimated using the `edf`, why are we using `reference edf`?

This is a sample R code:

````
set.seed(123)
library(mgcv)
x1=runif(100)
x2=runif(100)
y=exp(x1*pi) + x2^3 + rnorm(100)
M = gam(y~s(x1)+s(x2), method="REML")
summary(M)
  # AIC that takes the reference edf as edf! 
-2*logLik.gam(M) + 2*(sum(M$edf2)+1) == AIC(M)
[1] TRUE

```
````

Answer (score 1):

It's effective degrees of freedom for the smooth that is used in the test of the null hypothesis $\text{H}_0: f_j(x_{ji}) = \mathbf{0}$ (that the function is a constant 0 function).

There are at least three definitions of the effective degrees of freedom for a smooth term (see `$edf`, `$edf1`, and `$edf2` components in a fitted GAM object). These represent different views on the complexity of the smooth, with the reference EDF being one view that is useful in tests (I believe this is `$edf1`). `$edf2` is an EDF that is corrected for having estimated the smoothing parameters, and `$edf` is the standard definition of EDF.